# Tomcat7 - httpclient 4.1 LSv1 ALERT: fatal, description = certificate_unknown simple self sighed keystore

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

i search this all over and i got mixed results in my case nothing helped this is what i did 
created simple self-signed certificate as shown in here in the "Quick Start" section 
and configured my tomcat like this :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv2Hello"
               keystoreFile="d:/tomcat-7.0.37/conf/keystore.jks" 
               keystorePass="password" 

               />
```

then in eclipse simple httpclient 4.1 
i set the code like this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;
public HttpClientImpl() 
{


    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        setupTrustManager();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


//set up a TrustManager
private void setupTrustManager()
{
     System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
    try {
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                            return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                    String authType) {
                            System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                    String authType) {
                            System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0,
                            String arg1)
                            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0,
                            String arg1)
                            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
        } }, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);  

// Use the above SSLContext to create your socket factory
 // Accept any hostname, so the self-signed certificates don't fail
   SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext,SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, port)); 

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, socketTimeoutMillis);  

// Use the above SSLContext to create your socket factory
   SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext,SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
   // Accept any hostname, so the self-signed certificates don't fail


SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(),port));
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, port)); 
defaulthttpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
defaulthttpclient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);       
UrlEncodedFormEntity query = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paymentParams);

String func = "";            
fullurl = url+":"+Integer.toString(port)+"/"+request_uri;

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(fullurl);       
httppost.setEntity(query);
HttpResponse response_ = defaulthttpclient.execute(httppost);
```

every thing is working nice , the problem is im getting authentication errors
in the client im getting :

```
ool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 946
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1413987622 bytes = { 42, 197, 67, 236, 59, 241, 223, 70, 232, 196, 70, 24, 97, 145, 140, 139, 185, 200, 172, 229, 4, 205, 28, 38, 202, 182, 212, 49 }
Session ID:  {84, 72, 189, 38, 74, 201, 198, 221, 165, 196, 34, 196, 10, 60, 73, 244, 242, 66, 82, 228, 211, 197, 215, 107, 40, 77, 101, 146, 22, 85, 49, 139}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 54 48   BD 26 2A C5 43 EC 3B F1  ...M..TH.&*.C.;.
0010: DF 46 E8 C4 46 18 61 91   8C 8B B9 C8 AC E5 04 CD  .F..F.a.........
0020: 1C 26 CA B6 D4 31 20 54   48 BD 26 4A C9 C6 DD A5  .&...1 TH.&J....
0030: C4 22 C4 0A 3C 49 F4 F2   42 52 E4 D3 C5 D7 6B 28  ."..<I..BR....k(
0040: 4D 65 92 16 55 31 8B 00   04 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  Me..U1..........
0050: 00                                                 .
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=meir, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=il
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 21103055174963825912170080271025199388835832308472667542588591744540990655507849424446213676856611727380220145525049404850862112728185308605349818074144410303885079047745318203862070338218614832229515393322834332469888248630124226478908042665892135859836457111268996432425668848657493085294071666088580689747786778800616038426586703911373910262596587176363643840398209988885102873446199011702688943594962302353860921168564329138527678573646965435233006214603210138287773845800410940549128498862894526276196993605817330834866503143392244923707537244433427217150446267457534066313077484260209736380113315540343676517243
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 23 10:28:40 IST 2014,
               To: Wed Jan 21 10:28:40 IST 2015]
  Issuer: CN=foo, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=il
  SerialNumber: [    156ad60f]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AE 81 EF F8 BE 14 F6 98   02 5A 12 FD 8F 73 8C F3  .........Z...s..
0010: 6B BE 5D C1                                        k.].
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 2C 25 A0 2F C7 24 0A 69   01 80 8F E1 B5 59 78 8C  ,%./.$.i.....Yx.
0010: C1 F6 30 17 2C 51 20 E0   5C 84 69 96 81 CE 52 7F  ..0.,Q .\.i...R.
0020: 1C 8F B5 DB 6F 6E CA 98   BA 12 D5 0F C2 AB 11 E5  ....on..........
0030: 7E 1F 4D BD 37 27 AA FE   70 09 AB 13 E2 DA 38 A8  ..M.7'..p.....8.
0040: 12 7D 19 0E E9 24 89 2C   6C 56 CA C8 35 94 07 67  .....$.,lV..5..g
0050: 7D F5 5A AA 4F 41 6D D3   D2 B1 D1 A9 DC EB 21 92  ..Z.OAm.......!.
0060: D3 EA 3F 94 73 40 65 5F   31 00 5F 2D 90 3A D7 91  ..?.s@e_1._-.:..
0070: 90 0A F8 96 D7 43 85 0E   65 EC 26 62 DA 3D C1 50  .....C..e.&b.=.P
0080: 1D E3 8F 21 D4 7E 75 A3   21 CB BB 70 B2 55 02 D2  ...!..u.!..p.U..
0090: A3 24 3F 28 F8 07 24 0F   9B 3C 9E 07 5F E5 31 95  .$?(..$..<.._.1.
00A0: 1D 87 00 A9 55 33 6C CB   DA CF 5E F8 03 3E DC C3  ....U3l...^..>..
00B0: 67 C3 FF 59 43 33 0E 0F   17 E5 1C 93 8C F5 69 B0  g..YC3........i.
00C0: 53 54 2B C1 96 A3 81 CB   29 73 72 26 B5 EE AA CE  ST+.....)sr&....
00D0: EB 9C 0C 1C 09 9F 7B DF   EB D0 28 37 C1 E0 2D 10  ..........(7..-.
00E0: 72 75 A9 AD 2F 30 94 31   E3 34 E0 BF F7 C8 31 E2  ru../0.1.4....1.
00F0: 2C FF 8A DA 82 C8 76 9E   52 90 BE 5C 09 E5 32 2A  ,.....v.R..\..2*

]
***
pool-1-thread-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
pool-1-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E                               .......
pool-1-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-1-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
pool-1-thread-1, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
2014-10-23 10:32:38,356 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG [DefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
 2014-10-23 10:32:38,356 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG [HttpClientImpl] retry count:1
 2014-10-23 10:32:38,356 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG [DefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
 pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
2014-10-23 10:32:38,356 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG [SingleClientConnManager] Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@1e80761
 Exception postHttpReqest function from http client :javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
Threads done working
```

and in the server im getting this :

```
Cipher suite:  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=foo, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=il
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 21103055174963825912170080271025199388835832308472667542588591744540990655507849424446213676856611727380220145525049404850862112728185
3086053498180741444103038850790477453182038620703382186148322295153933228343324698882486301242264789080426658921358598364571112689964324256688486
5749308529407166608858068974778677880061603842658670391137391026259658717636364384039820998888510287344619901170268894359496230235386092116856432
9138527678573646965435233006214603210138287773845800410940549128498862894526276196993605817330834866503143392244923707537244433427217150446267457
534066313077484260209736380113315540343676517243
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 23 10:28:40 IST 2014,
               To: Wed Jan 21 10:28:40 IST 2015]
  Issuer: CN=foo, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=il
  SerialNumber: [    156ad60f]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AE 81 EF F8 BE 14 F6 98   02 5A 12 FD 8F 73 8C F3  .........Z...s..
0010: 6B BE 5D C1                                        k.].
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 2C 25 A0 2F C7 24 0A 69   01 80 8F E1 B5 59 78 8C  ,%./.$.i.....Yx.
0010: C1 F6 30 17 2C 51 20 E0   5C 84 69 96 81 CE 52 7F  ..0.,Q .\.i...R.
0020: 1C 8F B5 DB 6F 6E CA 98   BA 12 D5 0F C2 AB 11 E5  ....on..........
0030: 7E 1F 4D BD 37 27 AA FE   70 09 AB 13 E2 DA 38 A8  ..M.7'..p.....8.
0040: 12 7D 19 0E E9 24 89 2C   6C 56 CA C8 35 94 07 67  .....$.,lV..5..g
0050: 7D F5 5A AA 4F 41 6D D3   D2 B1 D1 A9 DC EB 21 92  ..Z.OAm.......!.
0060: D3 EA 3F 94 73 40 65 5F   31 00 5F 2D 90 3A D7 91  ..?.s@e_1._-.:..
0070: 90 0A F8 96 D7 43 85 0E   65 EC 26 62 DA 3D C1 50  .....C..e.&b.=.P
0080: 1D E3 8F 21 D4 7E 75 A3   21 CB BB 70 B2 55 02 D2  ...!..u.!..p.U..
0090: A3 24 3F 28 F8 07 24 0F   9B 3C 9E 07 5F E5 31 95  .$?(..$..<.._.1.
00A0: 1D 87 00 A9 55 33 6C CB   DA CF 5E F8 03 3E DC C3  ....U3l...^..>..
00B0: 67 C3 FF 59 43 33 0E 0F   17 E5 1C 93 8C F5 69 B0  g..YC3........i.
00C0: 53 54 2B C1 96 A3 81 CB   29 73 72 26 B5 EE AA CE  ST+.....)sr&....
00D0: EB 9C 0C 1C 09 9F 7B DF   EB D0 28 37 C1 E0 2D 10  ..........(7..-.
00E0: 72 75 A9 AD 2F 30 94 31   E3 34 E0 BF F7 C8 31 E2  ru../0.1.4....1.
00F0: 2C FF 8A DA 82 C8 76 9E   52 90 BE 5C 09 E5 32 2A  ,.....v.R..\..2*

]
***
*** ServerHelloDone
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 946
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 54 48   BD 26 2A C5 43 EC 3B F1  ...M..TH.&*.C.;.
0010: DF 46 E8 C4 46 18 61 91   8C 8B B9 C8 AC E5 04 CD  .F..F.a.........
0020: 1C 26 CA B6 D4 31 20 54   48 BD 26 4A C9 C6 DD A5  .&...1 TH.&J....
0030: C4 22 C4 0A 3C 49 F4 F2   42 52 E4 D3 C5 D7 6B 28  ."..<I..BR....k(
0040: 4D 65 92 16 55 31 8B 00   04 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  Me..U1..........
0050: 00 0B 00 03 59 00 03 56   00 03 53 30 82 03 4F 30  ....Y..V..S0..O0
0060: 82 02 37 A0 03 02 01 02   02 04 15 6A D6 0F 30 0D  ..7........j..0.
0070: 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D   01 01 0B 05 00 30 58 31  ..*.H........0X1
0080: 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06   13 02 69 6C 31 0D 30 0B  .0...U....il1.0.
0090: 06 03 55 04 08 13 04 6D   65 69 72 31 0D 30 0B 06  ..U....foo1.0..
00A0: 03 55 04 07 13 04 6D 65   69 72 31 0D 30 0B 06 03  .U....foo1.0...
00B0: 55 04 0A 13 04 6D 65 69   72 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55  U....foo1.0...U
00C0: 04 0B 13 04 6D 65 69 72   31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04  ....foo1.0...U.
00D0: 03 13 04 6D 65 69 72 30   1E 17 0D 31 34 31 30 32  ...foo0...14102
00E0: 33 30 38 32 38 34 30 5A   17 0D 31 35 30 31 32 31  3082840Z..150121
00F0: 30 38 32 38 34 30 5A 30   58 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55  082840Z0X1.0...U
0100: 04 06 13 02 69 6C 31 0D   30 0B 06 03 55 04 08 13  ....il1.0...U...
0110: 04 6D 65 69 72 31 0D 30   0B 06 03 55 04 07 13 04  .foo1.0...U....
0120: 6D 65 69 72 31 0D 30 0B   06 03 55 04 0A 13 04 6D  foo1.0...U....m
0130: 65 69 72 31 0D 30 0B 06   03 55 04 0B 13 04 6D 65  eir1.0...U....me
0140: 69 72 31 0D 30 0B 06 03   55 04 03 13 04 6D 65 69  ir1.0...U....mei
0150: 72 30 82 01 22 30 0D 06   09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01  r0.."0...*.H....
0160: 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0F   00 30 82 01 0A 02 82 01  .........0......
0170: 01 00 A7 2B 1C 1D 4E C1   76 BF D0 3D 79 12 4A A4  ...+..N.v..=y.J.
0180: 86 81 AD AF D2 F4 FE 53   A9 D8 8F D2 B0 75 63 8E  .......S.....uc.
0190: 07 2E FF C2 01 87 8F 3F   16 FC B4 DD 73 C4 56 22  .......?....s.V"
01A0: 56 6A 8C F4 E3 BF F5 9B   A0 F5 65 A5 CD 03 5C 0F  Vj........e...\.
01B0: 6D 7B 9D D0 C6 B7 31 59   DF 1A EB EF 1D 05 2B BF  m.....1Y......+.
01C0: F2 A8 62 6E 7C F8 C9 31   BE 07 0F B1 72 AD 15 E6  ..bn...1....r...
01D0: 6A 92 8C F6 D9 46 58 F6   2E F7 30 A1 A2 78 3D 46  j....FX...0..x=F
01E0: FC 0C 2E 4A FD 37 6D 13   EE E0 C6 6F DC 1C 06 AF  ...J.7m....o....
01F0: 68 A3 D1 D8 1C 75 A1 43   D4 5F 94 44 6A 4A C2 D9  h....u.C._.DjJ..
0200: 1A F2 A0 88 9C 19 DB EF   BF 31 85 19 62 78 55 33  .........1..bxU3
0210: C8 79 12 98 5D 73 EE D7   D7 89 04 FB D8 16 51 65  .y..]s........Qe
0220: AC B5 7E 8C A6 0F 56 C4   18 44 EF 01 FA A6 29 44  ......V..D....)D
0230: 5C D1 12 6D 66 E8 E9 C9   83 6F 7E 55 20 84 7C EE  \..mf....o.U ...
0240: BD 2C F5 3A BE D3 27 FD   24 70 56 51 C9 FB D1 5C  .,.:..'.$pVQ...\
0250: 03 69 80 9C BB 4B DA 55   56 C8 0F DB 32 DD C4 44  .i...K.UV...2..D
0260: CF 41 33 7D 6A AC 2B BB   2B 40 88 94 5D 51 F1 C8  .A3.j.+.+@..]Q..
0270: BB 7B 02 03 01 00 01 A3   21 30 1F 30 1D 06 03 55  ........!0.0...U
0280: 1D 0E 04 16 04 14 AE 81   EF F8 BE 14 F6 98 02 5A  ...............Z
0290: 12 FD 8F 73 8C F3 6B BE   5D C1 30 0D 06 09 2A 86  ...s..k.].0...*.
02A0: 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0B 05   00 03 82 01 01 00 2C 25  H.............,%
02B0: A0 2F C7 24 0A 69 01 80   8F E1 B5 59 78 8C C1 F6  ./.$.i.....Yx...
02C0: 30 17 2C 51 20 E0 5C 84   69 96 81 CE 52 7F 1C 8F  0.,Q .\.i...R...
02D0: B5 DB 6F 6E CA 98 BA 12   D5 0F C2 AB 11 E5 7E 1F  ..on............
02E0: 4D BD 37 27 AA FE 70 09   AB 13 E2 DA 38 A8 12 7D  M.7'..p.....8...
02F0: 19 0E E9 24 89 2C 6C 56   CA C8 35 94 07 67 7D F5  ...$.,lV..5..g..
0300: 5A AA 4F 41 6D D3 D2 B1   D1 A9 DC EB 21 92 D3 EA  Z.OAm.......!...
0310: 3F 94 73 40 65 5F 31 00   5F 2D 90 3A D7 91 90 0A  ?.s@e_1._-.:....
0320: F8 96 D7 43 85 0E 65 EC   26 62 DA 3D C1 50 1D E3  ...C..e.&b.=.P..
0330: 8F 21 D4 7E 75 A3 21 CB   BB 70 B2 55 02 D2 A3 24  .!..u.!..p.U...$
0340: 3F 28 F8 07 24 0F 9B 3C   9E 07 5F E5 31 95 1D 87  ?(..$..<.._.1...
0350: 00 A9 55 33 6C CB DA CF   5E F8 03 3E DC C3 67 C3  ..U3l...^..>..g.
0360: FF 59 43 33 0E 0F 17 E5   1C 93 8C F5 69 B0 53 54  .YC3........i.ST
0370: 2B C1 96 A3 81 CB 29 73   72 26 B5 EE AA CE EB 9C  +.....)sr&......
0380: 0C 1C 09 9F 7B DF EB D0   28 37 C1 E0 2D 10 72 75  ........(7..-.ru
0390: A9 AD 2F 30 94 31 E3 34   E0 BF F7 C8 31 E2 2C FF  ../0.1.4....1.,.
03A0: 8A DA 82 C8 76 9E 52 90   BE 5C 09 E5 32 2A 0E 00  ....v.R..\..2*..
03B0: 00 00                                              ..
http-bio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 946
[Raw write]: length = 951
0000: 16 03 01 03 B2 02 00 00   4D 03 01 54 48 BD 26 2A  ........M..TH.&*
0010: C5 43 EC 3B F1 DF 46 E8   C4 46 18 61 91 8C 8B B9  .C.;..F..F.a....
0020: C8 AC E5 04 CD 1C 26 CA   B6 D4 31 20 54 48 BD 26  ......&...1 TH.&
0030: 4A C9 C6 DD A5 C4 22 C4   0A 3C 49 F4 F2 42 52 E4  J....."..<I..BR.
0040: D3 C5 D7 6B 28 4D 65 92   16 55 31 8B 00 04 00 00  ...k(Me..U1.....
0050: 05 FF 01 00 01 00 0B 00   03 59 00 03 56 00 03 53  .........Y..V..S
0060: 30 82 03 4F 30 82 02 37   A0 03 02 01 02 02 04 15  0..O0..7........
0070: 6A D6 0F 30 0D 06 09 2A   86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0B  j..0...*.H......
0080: 05 00 30 58 31 0B 30 09   06 03 55 04 06 13 02 69  ..0X1.0...U....i
0090: 6C 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55   04 08 13 04 6D 65 69 72  l1.0...U....foo
00A0: 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04   07 13 04 6D 65 69 72 31  1.0...U....foo1
00B0: 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04 0A   13 04 6D 65 69 72 31 0D  .0...U....foo1.
00C0: 30 0B 06 03 55 04 0B 13   04 6D 65 69 72 31 0D 30  0...U....foo1.0
00D0: 0B 06 03 55 04 03 13 04   6D 65 69 72 30 1E 17 0D  ...U....foo0...
00E0: 31 34 31 30 32 33 30 38   32 38 34 30 5A 17 0D 31  141023082840Z..1
00F0: 35 30 31 32 31 30 38 32   38 34 30 5A 30 58 31 0B  50121082840Z0X1.
0100: 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13   02 69 6C 31 0D 30 0B 06  0...U....il1.0..
0110: 03 55 04 08 13 04 6D 65   69 72 31 0D 30 0B 06 03  .U....foo1.0...
0120: 55 04 07 13 04 6D 65 69   72 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55  U....foo1.0...U
0130: 04 0A 13 04 6D 65 69 72   31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04  ....foo1.0...U.
0140: 0B 13 04 6D 65 69 72 31   0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04 03  ...foo1.0...U..
0150: 13 04 6D 65 69 72 30 82   01 22 30 0D 06 09 2A 86  ..foo0.."0...*.
0160: 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05   00 03 82 01 0F 00 30 82  H.............0.
0170: 01 0A 02 82 01 01 00 A7   2B 1C 1D 4E C1 76 BF D0  ........+..N.v..
0180: 3D 79 12 4A A4 86 81 AD   AF D2 F4 FE 53 A9 D8 8F  =y.J........S...
0190: D2 B0 75 63 8E 07 2E FF   C2 01 87 8F 3F 16 FC B4  ..uc........?...
01A0: DD 73 C4 56 22 56 6A 8C   F4 E3 BF F5 9B A0 F5 65  .s.V"Vj........e
01B0: A5 CD 03 5C 0F 6D 7B 9D   D0 C6 B7 31 59 DF 1A EB  ...\.m.....1Y...
01C0: EF 1D 05 2B BF F2 A8 62   6E 7C F8 C9 31 BE 07 0F  ...+...bn...1...
01D0: B1 72 AD 15 E6 6A 92 8C   F6 D9 46 58 F6 2E F7 30  .r...j....FX...0
01E0: A1 A2 78 3D 46 FC 0C 2E   4A FD 37 6D 13 EE E0 C6  ..x=F...J.7m....
01F0: 6F DC 1C 06 AF 68 A3 D1   D8 1C 75 A1 43 D4 5F 94  o....h....u.C._.
0200: 44 6A 4A C2 D9 1A F2 A0   88 9C 19 DB EF BF 31 85  DjJ...........1.
0210: 19 62 78 55 33 C8 79 12   98 5D 73 EE D7 D7 89 04  .bxU3.y..]s.....
0220: FB D8 16 51 65 AC B5 7E   8C A6 0F 56 C4 18 44 EF  ...Qe......V..D.
0230: 01 FA A6 29 44 5C D1 12   6D 66 E8 E9 C9 83 6F 7E  ...)D\..mf....o.
0240: 55 20 84 7C EE BD 2C F5   3A BE D3 27 FD 24 70 56  U ....,.:..'.$pV
0250: 51 C9 FB D1 5C 03 69 80   9C BB 4B DA 55 56 C8 0F  Q...\.i...K.UV..
0260: DB 32 DD C4 44 CF 41 33   7D 6A AC 2B BB 2B 40 88  .2..D.A3.j.+.+@.
0270: 94 5D 51 F1 C8 BB 7B 02   03 01 00 01 A3 21 30 1F  .]Q..........!0.
0280: 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E 04   16 04 14 AE 81 EF F8 BE  0...U...........
0290: 14 F6 98 02 5A 12 FD 8F   73 8C F3 6B BE 5D C1 30  ....Z...s..k.].0
02A0: 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7   0D 01 01 0B 05 00 03 82  ...*.H..........
02B0: 01 01 00 2C 25 A0 2F C7   24 0A 69 01 80 8F E1 B5  ...,%./.$.i.....
02C0: 59 78 8C C1 F6 30 17 2C   51 20 E0 5C 84 69 96 81  Yx...0.,Q .\.i..
02D0: CE 52 7F 1C 8F B5 DB 6F   6E CA 98 BA 12 D5 0F C2  .R.....on.......
02E0: AB 11 E5 7E 1F 4D BD 37   27 AA FE 70 09 AB 13 E2  .....M.7'..p....
02F0: DA 38 A8 12 7D 19 0E E9   24 89 2C 6C 56 CA C8 35  .8......$.,lV..5
0300: 94 07 67 7D F5 5A AA 4F   41 6D D3 D2 B1 D1 A9 DC  ..g..Z.OAm......
0310: EB 21 92 D3 EA 3F 94 73   40 65 5F 31 00 5F 2D 90  .!...?.s@e_1._-.
0320: 3A D7 91 90 0A F8 96 D7   43 85 0E 65 EC 26 62 DA  :.......C..e.&b.
0330: 3D C1 50 1D E3 8F 21 D4   7E 75 A3 21 CB BB 70 B2  =.P...!..u.!..p.
0340: 55 02 D2 A3 24 3F 28 F8   07 24 0F 9B 3C 9E 07 5F  U...$?(..$..<.._
0350: E5 31 95 1D 87 00 A9 55   33 6C CB DA CF 5E F8 03  .1.....U3l...^..
0360: 3E DC C3 67 C3 FF 59 43   33 0E 0F 17 E5 1C 93 8C  >..g..YC3.......
0370: F5 69 B0 53 54 2B C1 96   A3 81 CB 29 73 72 26 B5  .i.ST+.....)sr&.
0380: EE AA CE EB 9C 0C 1C 09   9F 7B DF EB D0 28 37 C1  .............(7.
0390: E0 2D 10 72 75 A9 AD 2F   30 94 31 E3 34 E0 BF F7  .-.ru../0.1.4...
03A0: C8 31 E2 2C FF 8A DA 82   C8 76 9E 52 90 BE 5C 09  .1.,.....v.R..\.
03B0: E5 32 2A 0E 00 00 00                               .2*....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 2E                                              ..
http-bio-8443-exec-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8443-exec-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8443-exec-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-bio-8443-exec-1, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called close()
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

i think i tired every example i found in the web , i must be missing here something very basic .
that i don't have idea what it is